# Kotlin Room Cooroutines return value from query

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, kotlin-coroutines

I wish to return a value from an insert query when using Kotlin, room and co-routines

This is my code in sequence from ViewModel to Repo to DAO.  I would like to return the result of the insert call in the first ViewModel call but I cannot figure out how to

ViewModel

```
 fun insert(collectionItem: CollectionItem) = viewModelScope.launch {
        repository.insertCollectionItem(collectionItem)
    }
```

Repository

```
suspend fun insertCollectionItem(coll: CollectionItem): Long {
        return mCollectionItemDao.insert(coll)
    }
```

DAO

```
 @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insert(coll: CollectionItem): Long
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do one of:

```kotlin
suspend fun insert(collectionItem: CollectionItem): Long {
    return repository.insertCollectionItem(collectionItem)
}

viewModel.insert(item)
```

```kotlin
fun insert(collectionItem: CollectionItem) = viewModelScope.async {
    repository.insertCollectionItem(collectionItem)
}

viewModel.insert(item).await()
```

```kotlin
fun insert(collectionItem: CollectionItem) = runBlocking {
    repository.insertCollectionItem(collectionItem)
}

viewModel.insert(item)
```

You probably don't want the last one. The choice depends on what the consumer is doing.

Comment: This did not work in my use case but thank you for taking the time to help

Answer (score 0):

Declate a [LiveData](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata) variable in your `ViewModel` and observe it in your view(Activity, Fragment) and when your `couroutine` finishes post the return value of insert query to the `LiveData` variable which can then inform your view.

In this way you don't wait for your insert query to complete, instead you simply start the query and observe the `LiveData`, which informs you of the result.

In your ViewModel

```
// Declare LiveData variable
val rowsInserted: MutableLiveData<Int> = MutableLiveData()

//Update your coroutine
fun insert(collectionItem: CollectionItem) = viewModelScope.launch {
    val result = repository.insertCollectionItem(collectionItem)
    rowsInserted.postValue(result)
}
```

And observe the LiveData in your activity to get the result of insert

```
viewModel.rowsInserted.observe(this, Observer {
   Log.d(TAG, "$it rows inserted");
  }
)
```